# Add-Migration stalls after build is successful

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

I am trying to add a migration for my project. Everytime I try to add a migration it stalls after Build Succeeded. I have been working on the project for about 2-3 weeks and this has not happened yet. Could how I am mapping my data be causing this?

The program has 3 classes Person, TaskItem, and Day.

Day has a list of Tasks (that will be assigned to the people), and a list of People.

Person has a list of tasks, but does not have a reference to a day.

TaskItem needs a Navigation for People and Day.

**DbContect Class**

```
    using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using TaskDelegatingApp.Models;


namespace TaskDelegatingApp.Data
{
    public class TaskDelegatingAppContext : DbContext
    {
        public TaskDelegatingAppContext(DbContextOptions<TaskDelegatingAppContext> options)
            : base(options)
        { }

        public DbSet<Person> Person { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TaskDelegatingApp.Models.Day> Day { get; set; }

        public DbSet<TaskDelegatingApp.Models.TaskItem> TaskItem { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {

            modelBuilder.Entity<TaskItem>()
                .HasMany(c => c.People).WithMany(e => e.TaskItems).UsingEntity<Person>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Day>().HasMany(e => e.TaskItems).WithMany(e => e.Day).UsingEntity<TaskItem>();

            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>().HasMany(e => e.TaskItems).WithOne(e => e.Person).OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relations were not correct. They are corrected now.